# GraphQL custom scalar (LocalDateTime) not working with JSON input in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

In our GraphQL SpringBoot application we are successfully using custom scalar implementation for **LocalDateTime** via [graphql-java-datetime](https://github.com/donbeave/graphql-java-datetime)

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.zhokhov.graphql</groupId>
   <artifactId>graphql-datetime-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
   <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
   <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It is all working fine as long as we are only using it as **String** in schema

```
scalar LocalDateTime

input AttendanceFilter {
    # date format yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss
    fromDateTime: String
    toDateTime: String
}

type Query {
    attendanceList(filter: AttendanceFilter): [Attendance]
} 

type Attendance {
    date: LocalDateTime
}
```

we can also use Java type of LocalDateTime in Java resolvers implementation

```
public List<AttendancePOJO> attendanceList(AttendanceFilter filter) {
    LocalDateTime fromDateTime = filter.getFromDateTime;
    LocalDateTime toDateTime = filter.getToDateTime;
    return jpaAttendanceRepository.findByFromTimeAfterAndToTimeBefore(fromDateTime, toDateTime) }

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateTimeDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.LocalDateTimeSerializer;

public class AttendanceFilter {
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy[-]MM[-]dd'T'HH[:]mm[:]ss")
    private LocalDateTime fromDateTime;

    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy[-]MM[-]dd'T'HH[:]mm[:]ss")
    private LocalDateTime toDateTime;
}
```

And GraphQL query such as

```
query: {
  attendanceList(filter: {fromDateTime: "2018-01-01T00:00:00", 
    toDateTime: "2018-06-01T23:59:59"}) { date }
}
```

works just fine.

**But when we wanted to make it more readable, and instead of *String* parameter with fixed format to use *LocalDateTime* even in schema query.graphqls**

```
input AttendanceFilter {
    # date format yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss
    fromDateTime: LocalDateTime
    toDateTime: LocalDateTime
}
```

**the deserialization does not seem to work properly and returns an error**

```
Exception while fetching data (/attendanceList) : Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected VALUE_STRING: Expected array or string. at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: ***.AttendanceFilter["fromDateTime"])
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected VALUE_STRING: Expected array or string. at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: ***.AttendanceFilter["fromDateTime"])
```

Can anybody please suggest how to convert the values of JSON input in AttendanceFilter object into Java? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Did you find an answer, by any chance?